# C++ generate random numbers for a given seed

Tags: c++, random, random-seed, srand

I need to create a random number generator that generates n random numbers for a given seed s. k largest or smallest values generated are also known.

ex1 :

Seed (s): 123

No of random numbers (n):100

largest 10 random numbers sorted:
7523372
29439913
58320284
86168869
91064068
92596215
95168426
128959393
150074451
246577027

ex2 :

Seed (s): 12345

No of random numbers (n):1000000

smallest 50 random numbers largest to smallest:
2147483534
2147483066
2147478401
2147475092
2147470457
2147463295
2147460100
2147455072
2147454293
2147453287
2147450344
2147449403
2147448482
2147446509
2147444055
2147443731
2147443589
2147442701
2147436885
2147434035
2147429273
2147427145
2147426476
2147423920
2147417804
2147414079
2147407803
2147407048
2147386660
2147382475
2147381554
2147373468
2147372380
2147367051
2147366858
2147365895
2147358392
2147355655
2147344012
2147338974
2147338218
2147331959
2147312904
2147311693
2147288461
2147277290
2147265613
2147244881
2147175859
2147145872

But the random number generator I have code is not generating the required random numbers.

For ex1 :

The random numbers generated are
440
19053
23075
13104
32363
3265
30749
32678
9760
28064
20429
750
4480
3863
30429
18586
30758
31595
31567
24630
16059
2734
703
3966
12383
18065
28392
29902
26443
16505
11114
11737
10421
3541
2251
22174
14324
24238
18619
29848
25829
25215
16284
8757
22925
28488
12097
3722
27392
7902
16118
9541
29057
22149
13505
29411
27626
27840
21480
6435
29263
24936
1203
26554
15326
23548
10611
27976
15369
25656
17603
5259
6888
2281
21774
8658
3288
26879
2386
9397
19817
21220
13091
12804
16759
28172
6642
31229
1174
8910
5007
3778
26036
13426
1517
28426
5881
16779
13862
10518

which doesnt have any of the largest 10 numbers given.

Below is the code I have now.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    srand(123);

    //int range = 2147483647  + 1;

    int num;
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
       num = rand();// % range ;
       cout << num << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks to me like you must know the specific pseudo-random algorithm that produces the expected output. It's very unlikely that anyone on Stackoverflow will have access to quantum supercomputers with sufficient power to crunch through all possible pseudo-random number generators, and find the one that produces the expected output.

Comment: *"I need to create a random number generator that generates n random numbers for a given seed s."* -- This requirement seems rather tame. Most pseudo-random number generators are able to generate an arbitrary number of random numbers for a given seed s. I think you should choose a different requirement as your defining property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) (which you really should read!):

> Returns a pseudo-random integral value between ​0​ and RAND_MAX

Where `RAND_MAX` is implementation defined, but is guaranteed to be at least 32767.  In fact, it often *is* 32767, and that appears to apply to you.

The documentation also states:

> rand() is not recommended for serious random-number generation needs. It is recommended to use C++11's [random number generation facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) to replace rand().

And that is what I would advise you to do.

But as for getting specific output, that's another thing.  It's a strange requirement, where is it coming from?